# Баг связанный с присвоением GameObject

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код:

```
private GameObject PastObj;
private GameObject[] AllUsing;
public int Offset;

private void Awake()
{
    if (name != "1")
    {
        AllUsing = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("CatUpgradesParent");
        foreach (GameObject Obj in AllUsing) if (Obj.name == (Int32.Parse(name) - 1).ToString()) PastObj = Obj;
        Debug.Log(name + " | " + GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition.y + " - " + PastObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition.y + " obj " + PastObj.name + " " + PastObj.transform.root.GetComponent<CatUpgrade>().islight);
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if (PastObj.transform.root.GetComponent<CatUpgrade>().islight) Offset = -50;
    else Offset = -150;
    if (name != "1" && GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition.y - PastObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition.y != Offset) transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, 1) * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

В массиве AllUsing элементы с именами:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

В методе `Awake()` foreach должен из всех элементов массива AllUsing найти тот, у которого имя соответствует имени элемента на котором скрипт - 1. Но PastObj всегда оказывается пустым. Почему?

UPD: Этот скрипт висит на всех объектах массива AllUsing и все они с тегом CatUpgradesParent

Comment: Этот скрипт у вас в одиночном экзепляре? Или он висит в том числе и на объекте с именем 1?

Comment: Он висит на всех объектах массива AllUsing + у всех этих элементов тег CatUpgradesParent @M.Green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ссылка PastObj не всегда пустая. Она пустая только для объекта с именем "1".
В Awake() вы выполняете поиск и назначение в PastObj для всех экземпляров класса, кроме того, который висит на объекте с именем "1".

А в цикле Update() вы ещё до проверки имени уже пытаетесь обратиться через ссылку PastObj к его трансформации.

Т.к. в скрипте на объекте "1" в Awake() ссылка не была назначена, а в начале Update перед обращением вы не проверяете ни ссылку ни имя, то вам выдаёт исключение.